# React how to render async data from api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am using preact(light version of react) but syntax is almost the same. I am having an issue displaying verified after setting state from promise result. This is my container component:

```
import { h, Component } from "preact";
import { VerifierService } from "services/verifierService";
var CONFIG = require("Config");

//import * as styles from './profile.css';

interface PassportProps { token?: string; path?: string }
interface PassportState { appId?: string; verified?: boolean }

export default class Passport extends Component<PassportProps, PassportState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { appId: CONFIG.Settings.AppId };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("cdm: " + this.props.token);

    if (this.props.token != undefined) {
      await VerifierService.post({ token: this.props.token })
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({ verified: data.result });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Test: {this.state.verified}</div>;
  }
}
```

I can see console.log as true inside of promise result, but i can't display it in view.

Comment: What does your data look like in the `console.log`?

Comment: "true" as boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` in your `console.log` is `true`, so therefor `data.result` will give you `undefined`. Try to just set the `data` in `setState`.

```
await VerifierService.post({ token: this.props.token })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ verified: data });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Actually data is true but that doesn’t map with my model since model result is Boolean, have to fix that. Can you confirm life cycle is ok though?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic Yes, your code looks fine. Since you are using `async/await` you could also write `const data = await VerifierService.post({ token: this.props.token }); this.setState({ verified: data });` if you think that's more readable.

Comment: also boolean cannot be rendered, we have to convert it to string